# How to include zeros and null in the aggregation COUNT with some constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, null

[image]

I have the below table, I have to count the number of quant that is between `before_avg` and `after_avg` in a `cust, prod, month` combination. I have to make sure the count for month January and December is `null` because there is no month before January and there is no month after December, and you cannot check if a value is between a `null` and an `int`.  And I also need to make sure for rest of the month, if there is no quantity between `before_avg` and `after_avg`, I need to display `0`. I tried simple approach like using `between` clause. This just filtered out any count that is either `0` or `null`. I also tried to separate out month January and December, and try to make the count showing as zero. I actually look up on Stack Overflow, people say we can do `left join` or  `right join` to make it happen. I tried and since I have `three keys` in group by, it didn't seem to work very well.

I know a lot of you guys may suggest functions like `nvl` to do the job, but unfortunately, I am only allow to use standard SQL syntax.

Therefore, I am asking for advices and suggestions on how to approach this? I can write queries, but I need some ideas and thoughts from you guys!

Thank you very much!!

Below is some sample code I created for you guys to try: (This is in PostgreSQL)

```
create table abc (
    cust varchar(20), 
    prod varchar(20),
    month integer,
    quant integer,
    before_avg integer, 
    after_avg integer) 
    
insert into abc values ('Boo', 'Apple', 1, 399, null, 461); 
insert into abc values ('Boo', 'Apple', 1, 650, null, 461); 
insert into abc values ('Boo', 'Apple', 4,620, 400,303); 
insert into abc values ('Boo', 'Apple', 4,870, 400,303); 
insert into abc values ('Boo', 'Apple', 12,575,482,null);
insert into abc values ('Boo', 'Apple', 12,670,482, null); 

insert into abc values ('Chad', 'Banana', 1, 800, null, 461); 
insert into abc values ('Chad', 'Banana', 1, 445, null, 461); 
insert into abc values ('Chad', 'Banana', 4,456, 400,303); 
insert into abc values ('Chad', 'Banana', 4,237, 400,303); 
insert into abc values ('Chad', 'Banana', 12,523,482,null); 
insert into abc values ('Chad', 'Banana', 12,584,482, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have the below table, I have to count the number of quant that is between before_avg and after_avg in a cust, prod, month

This sounds like aggregation:

```
select cust, prod, month,
       count(*) filter (where quant between before_avg and after_avg)
from abc
group by cust, prod, month;
```

You can write this without filter (which seems silly, given that `filter` is ISO SQL standard syntax):

```
select cust, prod, month,
       sum( (quant between before_avg and after_avg)::int )
from abc
group by cust, prod, month;
```

Comment: This works however I don't think I am allowed to use ```filter``` either. I need to use standard syntax. And this result does not produce ```null``` when month is 1 or 12.

Comment: `filter` **is** standard syntax.  SQL standard, yup.